# Does game development have its own types of modeling?

Tags: game-design, design-patterns, documentation, design-document

In general computer science there are modeling "languages" (read: standardized diagramming techniques) such as UML <sup>[1](http://www.uml.org/),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)</sup>, in databases there are things like ERD<sup>[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)</sup>, in business there are other types such as BPMN<sup>[4](http://www.bpmn.org/),[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation)</sup>. Is there anything like these that are Game Design specific?

Comment: Joris Dormans' [Machinations](http://jorisdormans.nl/machinations) is intended for modeling game mechanics. It's essentially a way to create interactive diagrams that represent resources and relationships in your game design.

Comment: Good answers to this question should have details and exposition. Please do not post answers that exist primarily to refer to tools that offer modeling capabilities; GDSE is not about collecting lists of equally-valid answers. See the [help] for more details. Improper answers may be removed.

Comment: The question title totally makes me assume 3D modeling. not sure what a better term would be

Answer (score 16):

There's no industry standard, but most high-profile studios do create a [game design document.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_design_document)

Game development, after all, encompasses quite a number of fields, so there will often be a combination of storyboarding, UML for the programming side, a script for dialogue, and so on.

That being said, the number one "modelling language" I've encountered: flow charts.

[image]

But that's hardly specific to game design!

Answer (score 7):

One of the actual models that I know about in game design is the MDA framework. This is the closest thing to your question that I can think of, as MDA gives you a reference to think and talk in (thus a language). And you can visualize it in a diagram if necessary.

A proper definition is given in [this paper by Hunicke et al](http://www.zubek.net/robert/publications/MDA.pdf), and I'll give a short description below.

### The MDA framework

In MDA **mechanics** are the things that you define in a game as a designer. An example of a mechanic could be - *"A timer starting at 60 and counting down by one every second. If it reaches zero the game is over."*

A **dynamic** describes the actual behaviour of a mechanic. Or in other words: the influence of a mechanic on your game. The timer mechanic would add a *time pressure* dynamic to your game.

The **aesthetics** of a game describe the overal feel and types of play in a game. The 8 basic aesthetics are:

1. Sensation (pleasure of the senses)
2. Fantasy (make believe)
3. Narrative (drama)
4. Challenge (obstacles to overcome)
5. Fellowship (social interaction)
6. Discovery (uncharted territory)
7. Expression (self-discovery)
8. Submission (pastime)

The aesthetic generated by a timer is challenge, because the time pressure is an obstacle. Note that you can add any new (sub-)aesthetics if necessary.

---

MDA allows you to reason about your game design both bottom-up and top-down. If there's some aesthetic in your game that you feel is not represented strongly enough, you can add more mechanics to support it. You could also model your game in a diagram using MDA by connecting the mechanics that support specific dynamics, and so on.

I learned about it in a game design course, but you can probably find some further reading on the web too. I hope this is what you were looking for, good luck!